# How to display "a" to full of the line

Tags: jquery, css

When mouseover of MAIN will display submenu but submenu not full display of the line.
How to make "SUB 1" under the MAIN 1 to full display in the line?

I do not want to set the width because submenu of another main have to short text.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="#" title="MAIN 1">MAIN 1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="SUB 1">SUB 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="SUB 1 XXXX XXXXX SUB 1">SUB 1 XXXX XXXXX SUB 1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#" title="MAIN 2">MAIN 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" title="MAIN 1">MAIN 3</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#" title="SUB 3">SUB 3 XXXX</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#" title="SUB 3 XXXX SUB 1">SUB 3 XXXX</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
```

**CSS**

```
#menu{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;}
#menu li{float:left;display:block;background:#ccc;position:relative;z-index:500;margin:0 1px;}
#menu li a{display:block;padding:4px 8px 0 8px;font-weight:700;height:23px;text-decoration:none;color:#4C4C4C;}
#menu li a:hover{color:#ffaa00;}
#menu a.selected{color:#f00;}
#menu ul{position:absolute;left:0;display:none;margin:0 0 0 -1px;padding:0;list-style:none;background-color:#000000}
#menu ul li{white-space:nowrap;float:left;border-top:1px solid #fff;}
#menu ul a{display:block;height:15px;padding:8px 5px;color:#666;text-align:left;}
#menu ul a:hover{text-decoration:underline;}
*html #menu ul{margin:0 0 0 -2px;}
```

**Javascript**

```
$('#menu li').hover(
                function () {
                    //show its submenu
                    $('ul', this).slideDown(100);

                },
                function () {
                    //hide its submenu
                    $('ul', this).slideUp(100);            
                }
            );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dgaxh/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There you go  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mJEuk/)

I simply added `width: 100%` to `#menu ul li` div id, by setting to 100% it will accommdate to the longest text from another row.

Comment: With welcome, you can mark my comment as accepted if this was the answer you was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

we can set width 100% of each li positions.

```
#menu li ul li {min-width:100%}
```